# How to shutdown a Microsoft Access database programatically without leaving a database shell

Tags: microsoft-access

Everytime I use application.quit it shuts down the database perfectly. The issue is that a shell database is left open on the taskbar. After an hour of processing I have 40 shells to manually close. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Try Application.close